# Webkit transform: rotate

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I've got a code:

HTML:

```
<section class="progress">
    <div class="spinner icon-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></div>
  <p class="label">Loading</p>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/icomoonfonts/4/6/f.eot');
    src:url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/icomoonfonts/4/6/f.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/icomoonfonts/4/6/f.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/icomoonfonts/4/6/f.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/icomoonfonts/4/6/f.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.icon-spinner:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    content: "\e002";
}

@keyframes anim-rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
    }
  50% {
    opacity: .7;
  }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    opacity: 1;
    }
}
.spinner {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:64px;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: .1em;
    animation: anim-rotate 3s infinite linear;
    color: rgba(223,78,107, 1);
}
body {
  text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background: #fff;
}
.progress {
  margin:2em;
}
.progress .label {
  color:#777;
  margin:0;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BfKaA/

Why does this `rotate(0deg); -> rotate(359deg);` shakes in Chrome during rotation?
This example in FF is working. Can anyone make code changes there to obtain smooth rotation in Chrome?

Comment: I can see no visible difference between firefox and Chrome34/Mac. The animation is smooth on both the browser

Comment: There is a slight non-uniform movement during the rotation, but it is not coming from the code. It comes from the icomoon character not being absolutely circular. So, I don't think that this problem can be eliminated

Comment: To me it works perfect in Chrome, but shakes in FF O_o

Answer (score 1):

Try that ...

```
  @keyframes anim-rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
    }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: I can even remove opacity change, it still shakes, problem is somewhere in webkit rotate method

Comment: im getting a perfect flowing rotate on google chrome, dropped the rotate to 1s and spins perfectly . alternatively you could use :  http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

Comment: maybe problem is somewhere in my chrome's version working on CentOS :/